# Terraform does not wait for update of azurerm_key_vault_secret.xyz.id

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

We are using terraform to build my azure resources with azurerm provider.
We are injecting a secret during the terraform run and this secret may change from time to time.
We use a azurerm_key_vault_secret to store the secret and a function app with managed identity (that has got reading access to the key vault) that receives the secret like this:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "my_secret" {
  name         = "my-secret"
  value        = var.my_secret
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.default.id
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "app" {
  name         = "..."
  app_settings = {
      MySecret = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${azurerm_key_vault_secret.my_secret.id})"
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  ...
}
```

When i run terraform apply and the secret is changed, the function app points to the old version of the secret. It seems the `azurerm_key_vault_secret.my_secret.id` is being read before the secret was updated.

Does anybody have any idea, how I can make sure the function_app will wait for the update of the secret?

(And yes, the id changes and I also don't like it, but that is how the provider works.)

Comment: You can introduce a delay, if you know how log it takes to update?

Comment: It is azure, so you never know, how long it will take. Also that is not a very clean solution and my current task is "cleaning up the terraform".

Comment: In that case you have to create custom data source, which will pull for the change. So you don't have to guess how long it will take.

Comment: How would I make sure the custom data source waits for the update of the resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "my_secret"?

Comment: You would have to program such a logic yourself using [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source).

Comment: I cannot believe that there is no easier solution...

Comment: I'm not providing an answer, just a comment, thus better way may be given in answer. But your issue is not new. Sadly, not all possible resources in TF are synchronous. Some are asynchronous, and TF does not wait for them to fully complete provisioning or update.

Comment: Oh, and also please make sure that you are using latest TF and azure provider. This could have been a bug, and maybe its already fixed.

Comment: Ok thanks. I hope somebody knows a better answer.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: I will wait some time to see if somebody provides a more elegant solution. If this won't happen, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are updating a key vault secret then the change is handled by Key vault UI . So Terraform won't detect the changes on `azurerm_key_vault_secret.example.id` and thus the reference's also won't be modified .

As a Workaround , You can use a **data source** for the same ***key vault secret*** and provide it in the ***function-app*** as shown in the below code , so that all the changes done in key vault secret can be read from data source and the changes can be applied accordingly :

```
  resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "functionappsecret"
  value        = "changedpassword"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  name="functionappsecret"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_secret.example
  ]
}
resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "ansuman-azure-functions"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  app_settings = {
      MySecret = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secret.id})"
  }

  identity {
    type="SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

**Ouptut:**

[image]

Comment: Ok from the log it seems to be working properly. But why is this working if adding the depends_on [ azurerm_key_vault_secret.example ] directly in the function app is not working properly?

Comment: @Woozar, as i have mentioned in answer the change in id is managed by keyvault ui from azure side ..  even if terraform creates it after apply only the id get changed .. but when data source is used you are telling terraform to check for all the properties that are changing when the secret value is changed.